# No data returned from database with php

Tags: php, sql-server, azure

I am building a PHP page to read data from an Azure SQL database. It seems like connection and query works, but I can't get any returned data to show.

The output I get on the web page is

> Connection established.
>   Statement executed.
>   There are rows.

```
<?php
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"sitrap", "UID"=>"xxxxxx@xxxxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxxx");
$serverName = "tcp:xxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$sql = "SELECT time, callsign FROM reports";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ( $stmt )  
{  
     echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";  
}   
else   
{  
     echo "Error in statement execution.\n";  
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}  
if ($stmt) {
   $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows( $stmt );
   if ($rows === true)
      echo "There are rows. <br />";
   else 
      echo "There are no rows. <br />";
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
{  
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["time"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["callsign"];?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn);  
?>
```

Comment: If you look into source html code - is there a `tr-td` markup?

Comment: Now sure I understand what you mean. But there are <TR>, </TR>, <TD> and </TD> in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP logfiles, I found that the problem was that "time" was returned in non-string format. When re-format the time format it started to work.

```
{    
  echo "Col1: ".$row[0]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";    
}
```